# Why apprend("<ul><li>")is so strange

Tags: jquery, append, html-lists

I got a problem with append in jquery

When i write the code like

---

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    for(var a=0;a<5;a++){
          var u=$("#nav").append("<li >a_"+a);
               u.append("<ul>");
                   for(var b=0;b<5;b++){
                       u.append("<li>b_"+b+"</li>");
                   }
                u.append("</ul>")

          $("#nav").append("</li>")
     }
    });

 </script>
  <div class="section-tree">
  <ul id="nav"></ul>         </div>
```

It output like:

[image]

Is not what i want

What i want is:

```
  <ul>

   <li> 
    a_0
      <ul>
         <li>b_1</li>
         <li>b_2</li>
         <li>b_3</li>
         <li>b_4</li>
         <li>b_5</li>
      </ul>
   </li>

   <li> 
   a_1
      <ul>
        <li>b_1</li>
        <li>b_2</li>
        <li>b_3</li>
        <li>b_4</li>
        <li>b_5</li>
      </ul>
  </li>
        ...
</ul>
```

### why it's not right?

hellowworld
hellowworld
hellowworld
hellowworld

Comment: _"why it's not right?"_ - because `.append` appends complete elements; you can not use it to “append a closing tag” only. Create a `ul` element, append the items to it, and then append the `ul` to the document.

Answer (score 2):

concatenate it to a variable first than use `.append()` see below snippet for more info.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = "";
  for (var a = 0; a < 5; a++) {
    data += "<li >a_" + a;
    data += "<ul>";
    for (var b = 0; b < 5; b++) {
      data += "<li>b_" + b + "</li>";
    }
    data += "</ul></li>";
  }
  $("#nav").append(data)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>


</script>
<div class="section-tree">
  <ul id="nav"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad it helps please marked as answer if you find it's useful to you.. please find [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to know how to marked as answer

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      var finalUiLi="";
      for(var a=0;a<5;a++){
          finalUiLi+="<li>a_"+a;
            finalUiLi+="<ul>";
                for(var b=0;b<5;b++){
                    finalUiLi+="<li>b_"+b +"</li>";
                }
            finalUiLi+="</ul>";   
          finalUiLi+="</li>";
      }
     $("#nav").append(finalUiLi);
    });
```

Please try this way it will work. Below is the screen shot for the output.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`.append()` append complete elements, You should create DOM element and then append it. Here is an example

*Use*

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (var a = 0; a < 5; a++) {
    //Create LI elementFromPoint
    var li = $("<li >a_" + a + "</li>");

    //Create Sub UL
    var u = $("<ul>");
    for (var b = 0; b < 5; b++) {
      u.append("<li>b_" + b + "</li>");
    }

    //Append Sub UL ti LI
    li.append(u);

    //Append li
    $("#nav").append(li)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section-tree">
  <ul id="nav"></ul>
</div>
```